# Devise custom mailer SMTPAPI headers & Sendgrid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using a devise custom mailer and have the signup process using my new method, however I'm getting the error `undefined local variable or method 'headers' for DeviseMailer:Class` when it's attempting to send the email after the signup.  I need to be able to specify SMTPAPI headers to be able to use my Sendgrid template.  I have this working for some other mailers (not devise related), so I've taken the same code and added it to my new devise mailer.

**models/devise_mailer.rb**

```
class DeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper :application
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer'

  def self.confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    new(:confirmation_instructions, record, token, opts)

    headers "X-SMTPAPI" => {
     "sub": {
      "-user-" => [user.name]
     },
     "filters": {
      "templates": {
        "settings": {
          "enable": 1,
          "template_id": "f67a241a-b5af-46b3-9e9a-xxxxxxxxx"
        }
      }
     }
    }.to_json

    mail(
      to: user.email,
      subject: "Confirm your account",
      template_path: '../views/devise/mailer',
      template_name: 'confirmation_instructions'
    )


    opts[:from] = 'support@mydomain.com'
    opts[:reply_to] = 'support@mydomain.com'
    opts[:to] = "myemail@mydomain.com" # just hardcoded right now, remove after testing
    super

  end
end
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `headers` is defined as an instance method, not a class method. Since you are trying to call it within the context of the class (i.e. `self.confirmation_instructions`), it is undefined.

If you notice in the [Devise wiki post](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer) on using custom mailers, the instructions reference `headers` on the instance, not the class.

---

If you just want to add some custom headers / options, the recommended approach is to just override the instance method then call `super`. For example

```
class DeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper :application
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer'

  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    # custom header(s)
    headers["X-SMTPAPI"]= {
     "sub": {
      "-user-" => [user.name]
     },
     "filters": {
      "templates": {
        "settings": {
          "enable": 1,
          "template_id": "f67a241a-b5af-46b3-9e9a-xxxxxxxxx"
        }
      }
     }
    }.to_json

    # custom option(s)
    opts[:from] = 'support@mydomain.com'
    opts[:reply_to] = 'support@mydomain.com'
    opts[:to] = "myemail@mydomain.com"

    super
  end
end
```

I recommend reading the linked blog post, as it talks about overriding the default behavior for mailers in more detail.

Comment: I guess that's where my problem lies... I don't have a controller to add a `confirmation_instructions` method to since it's all devise generated.  Do you know if I can override it with my own somehow?

Comment: The method does not get added to a controller, it goes in the custom mailer (just like you have it) except it needs to be an instance method rather than a class method. See my revised answer above.